# How to get specific page screen ID

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, id

Is it possible to get the screen id of a specific page? I've search on google and couldn't find anything related to specific page screen ID

I'm not looking for the get_current_screen() ID or the global $current_screen variable. What I'm looking for is to get the ID of a specific page when I'm not viewing the page.

for example:

I create a page like this dynamically

```
$hook = add_menu_page( 'Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-page-key', callback );
```

or

```
$hook = add_options_page( 'Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-page-key', callback );
```

I have no clue which the page will be registered since it's based on a settings value. Only can grab the 'my-custom-page-key', I need to get the $hook value outside of the page, maybe as a global variable ( last resort ).

so basically I'm looking for something like this

```
get_screen_id( 'my-custom-page-key' );
```

this will return value likes

`toplevel_page_my-custom-page-key` or `settings_page_my-custom-page-key`, etc

Comment: I think the closest the API gets is [`get_plugin_page_hookname`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hookname/), but you have to know if it's a top-level page or what its parent is in the case of an options or subpage.

Comment: Thanks for this solutions, it's so close, only need to find how to get to the parent page id

Comment: Could you pass as a `parameter`?

Comment: Or look at the `headers`? "Admin parent page should always be in the url somewhere I believe.

Comment: for custom menu page, all of the page is attached to admin.php no matter what is the parent menu. The global $pagenow = admin.php, while the prefix for page can be something else like, custom page registered to themes.php will have prefix appearance_page_, but the url of the page is admin.php, so passing admin.php to the parent page will generating admin_page_my-custom-page-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without accessing a global. This seems to work for all pages types, by using the global `$_parent_pages` with the function [`get_plugin_page_hookname`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hookname/):

```
function nackle_get_screen_id( $slug ){
    global $_parent_pages;
    $parent = array_key_exists( $slug, $_parent_pages ) ? $_parent_pages[$slug] : '';
    return get_plugin_page_hookname( $slug, $parent );
}
```

Usage example:

```
echo nackle_get_screen_id( 'my-custom-page-key' );
```

Edit- This can be used on or after `admin_init`, which is when the menu is parsed and `$_parent_pages` is populated.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works like a charm, PS: the function need to be called within admin_init or the $_parent_pages has nothing :)